# How to get value from array having key as @attribute in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using an API which returns an object after converting it into an array it gives following array. how to fetch the `AirPortName` from the below array?

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [AirPortName] => Indira Gandhi
            [CityName] => New Delhi
            [CodeContext] => IATA
            [LocationCode] => DEL
            [TerminalID] => 1B
        )

)
```

I am using following code to convert the object into array

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$p), TRUE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have object as keys, then you can do it like this:

```
foreach($your_array as $key => $values){
        // This is how you get Airport name
        echo $your_array->$key['AriportName'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After converting obj to array use

```
echo $array['@attributes']['AirPortName'];
```

Example :

```
$array = array('@attributes' => array('AirPortName' => 'Indira Gandhi','CityName' => 'New Delhi','CodeContext' => 'IATA','LocationCode' => 'DEL','TerminalID' => '1B' ));
echo $array['@attributes']['AirPortName'];
```

Will give You :

```
Indira Gandhi
```